# Symfony 6.2 API & Postman: return status code 200 on HttpException with different status code

Tags: php, api, symfony

When i throw an Http exception in my crud API, to avoid that symfony returns the complete error stack trace, i handle the exception with this listener:

```
class ExceptionListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        // You get the exception object from the received event
        $exception = $event->getThrowable();
        $message = sprintf(
            'My Error says: %s with code: %s',
            $exception->getMessage(),
            $exception->getCode()
        );

        // Customize your response object to display the exception details
        $response = new JsonResponse(['error' => $message]);

        // HttpExceptionInterface is a special type of exception that
        // holds status code and header details
        if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
            $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
            $response->headers->set( 'X-Status-Code', $exception->getStatusCode());
            $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
        } else {
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        // sends the modified response object to the event
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => ['onKernelException', 256],
        ];
    }
}
```

So on Postman i can see

```
{
    "error": "My Error says: Invalid body format with code: 0"
}
```

instead of the error stacktrace in html, but the status code remains 200.

[Response on postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9K5w.png)

Can you help me?

With xdebug i've seen that $response->statusCode is correctly setted to 400.

My service.yaml

```
  App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception,  method: onKernelException }
```